# Java Swing: Render Component incl. LaF into BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to render a table header cell into a `BufferedImage` with the following code:

```
Component component = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer().
        getTableCellRendererComponent( table, value, selected, focused, 0, 0 );

component.setBounds( 0, 0, 
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 0 ).getWidth(), 
                    table.getRowHeight() );

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage( component.getWidth(), 
                                       component.getHeight(),
                                       BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
g.setColor( component.getForeground() );
g.setFont( component.getFont() );
component.paint( g );
```

This code is run within the `TableCellRenderer#getTableCellRendererComponent` method.
The component is rendered into the BufferedImage but the Look-and-Feel was not applied before. The LaF has been set at application start to the system's default.

What do I need to do in order to render also the applied LaF of the component?

**Edit:**
*@Guillaume Polet:*
I run your code and I get the same results but once I render the whole table I see the following:
On Linux:
[image]
On Windows:
[image]
On Linux the code seems to work while in Windows it omits the LaF.
On Windows I would expect something like:
[image]

My code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.CellRendererPane;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

class TestPrint {

public static void main( String[] args ) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() );
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new TestPrint().run();
        }
    } );
}

protected void run() {
    JTable table = new JTable( createData() );
    int column = 1;

    TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

    Component component = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent( table, table.getColumnName( column ), false,
            false, -1, column );

    component.setBounds( 0, 0, table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 0 ).getWidth(), table.getRowHeight() );

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage( component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
    g.setClip( 0, 0, component.getWidth(), component.getHeight() );
    g.setColor( component.getForeground() );
    g.setFont( component.getFont() );

    CellRendererPane cellRendererPane = new CellRendererPane();
    cellRendererPane.paintComponent( g, component, table, 0, 0, component.getWidth(), component.getHeight() );

    // SwingUtilities.paintComponent( g, component, table,
    // new Rectangle( 0, 0, component.getWidth(), component.getHeight() ) );

    // component.paint( g );

    showTable( table );
    showImage( img );
}

private void showImage( BufferedImage img ) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, new JLabel( new ImageIcon( img ) ), "Test",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null );
}

private void showTable( JTable table ) {
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setViewportView( table );

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    frame.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    frame.setSize( 400, 300 );
    frame.setVisible( true );
}

private DefaultTableModel createData() {
    DefaultTableModel data = new DefaultTableModel( 0, 6 );

    for ( int i = 0; i < 30; i++ ) {
        Vector v = new Vector();

        for ( int k = 0; k < 6; k++ ) {
            v.add( new Float( k / (float) i ) );
        }

        data.addRow( v );
    }
    return data;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me (although it is not abvious the difference between the system L&F and the default one)

Example (above is native L&F and below is Metal):

[image]

And the code to create those (simply comment the first line of the main to see the default L&F)

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

class TestPrint {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestPrint().run();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void run() {
        JTable table = new JTable(new Vector<Vector<Object>>(), new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World")));
        int column = 1;
        Component component = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()
                .getTableCellRendererComponent(table, table.getColumnName(column), false, false, -1, column);
        component.setBounds(0, 0, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(), table.getRowHeight());
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(component.getForeground());
        g.setFont(component.getFont());
        component.paint(g);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)), "Test", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Indeed the Windows "Skin" is not properly painted. I am not exactly sure why it does not paint directly (probably because renderers are not "live" components). However, an easy trick is to print it too, is to print the entire table header but use a Graphics which is translated to the column header we want and clipped to the size of the column header:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

class TestPrint {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestPrint().run();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void run() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTable table = new JTable(new Vector<Vector<Object>>(), new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World")));
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        int column = 1;
        Rectangle headerRect = table.getTableHeader().getHeaderRect(column);
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(headerRect.width, headerRect.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.translate(-headerRect.width, 0);
        table.getTableHeader().print(g);
        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would've never come up with this solution on my own.